# Session/Cookies not getting set (Post, Redirect)

Tags: session, cookies, asp-classic

I'm having a big problem with Session and Cookies in Classic ASP.

I have "a.asp" where I set the `Session("step") = "1"`. This works and when I call my "test.asp" where I do `<%=Session("step")%>` I get "1".

Then I submit the form on "a.asp" to "process.asp" where I set other session-variables based on the submitted form values. Finally I redirect to "b.asp".

On "b.asp" I check if `Session("step") = "1"` and set it to "2" if it was "1" and redirect to "a.asp" otherwise. I write the `Session("step")` on the page and it says "2" but when I call "test.asp" it says "1".

It seems like the page itself got the right value but a reload or any other page ignores the change of session/cookie value.

Tried the same with Cookies (`Response.Cookies("step")`/`Request.Cookies("step")`) and I got the same result.

Pages are all in the same folder and there is only 1 worker-thread on the IIS.

Just can't figure out why the session and cookie are not getting set. Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

(Can't seem to comment, but need some clarification.  Will edit/delete this answer as appropriate. anyways....)

It *could* be a caching issue:

- Have you tried CTRL+F5 to make sure your browser is reloading.
- Try in another browser, I have found Firefox and Chrome both ignore forced cache refreshes sometimes, or try in "private" mode.
- Does your host have a load balancer or caching system?  Add a random querystring to each request to test.asp to make sure.
- You can force no-caching, but some browsers, ISPs and Hosters ignore it anyway...

.

```
Response.Expires = 0
Response.AddHeader "pragma","no-cache"
Response.AddHeader "cache-control","private"
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
```

Apologies if you have tried all this, would have rather asked with a quick comment!